# C# Confirm message Handler in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, ext.net

I need to open a dialog when I click a button so I here is what I have done:

Markup:

```
<ext:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Save New Information" OnDirectClick="Button1_DirectClick"/>
```

CodeBehind:

```
namespace Admin.Modules
{
    public partial class UsersGrid : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
    protected void Button1_DirectClick(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        X.Msg.Confirm("Confirm", "Do you want to update this information also?", new MessageBoxButtonsConfig
        {
            Yes = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
            {
                Handler = "App.Direct.DoYes()",
                Text = "Yes"
            },
            No = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
            {
                Handler = "WndwEdit.close()",
                Text = "No"
            }
        }).Show();
    }

    [DirectMethod]
    public void DoYes()
    {
        X.MessageBox.Info("Error NOT", "Something went lalala", AnchorPoint.LeftTop, UI.Danger).Show();
    }
}
}
```

The message box is displayed correctly but it doesnt call the DoYes function with error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DoYes' of undefined

Comment: Please include your namespace and class definition in your snippet.

Comment: @ChrisPickford ok done

Comment: Having never used ext.net I'm not familiar with their `DirectMethod` topology, however your error would suggest that your `DoYes()` method isn't being defined on the `App.Direct` namespace. Try playing about with `[DirectMethod(Namespace = "???"]`.

Comment: I tried with specific Namespace but didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

You need to use App.direct.DoYes not App.Direct.DoYes.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Button1_DirectClick(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        X.Msg.Confirm("Confirm", "Do you want to update this information also?", new MessageBoxButtonsConfig
        {
            Yes = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
            {
                Handler = "App.direct.DoYes()",
                Text = "Yes"
            },
            No = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
            {
                Handler = "WndwEdit.close()",
                Text = "No"
            }
        }).Show();
    }

    [DirectMethod]
    public void DoYes()
    {
        X.MessageBox.Info("Error NOT", "Something went lalala", AnchorPoint.LeftTop, UI.Danger).Show();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://speed.ext.net/www/intro/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" Theme="Triton" />

    <ext:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Save New Information" OnDirectClick="Button1_DirectClick"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I use App.direct.DoYes I receive this error: Uncaught TypeError: App.direct.DoYes is not a function

Comment: Try to change [DirectMethod] to [DirectMethod(Namespace = "App.direct")]

Also, check what values do you have in web.config for this value: directMethodNamespace

More information here: http://examples.ext.net/examples/Getting_Started/Release_Documents/README/